# Paint Win32 window to file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi

In a WPF application (C#), one of the elements is Win32 Window, created by overriding the HwndHost class.  There are about 10 instance of this Win32 window in the WPF at any given time.  One should render completely (works fine), and the other 9 should only show previews, without creating a Win32 window, just a bitmap.

I've been trying to find way to generate said bitmap.  Tried a lot of different things but nothing has really worked so far.  The main problem I run into is that HwndHost.WndProc is only called when the window is visible.

I can take a screenshot of a visible window, render it to memory and create a bitmap fine.. I just need some way of doing this while the window is not visible.

My understanding is still quite fuzzy, so any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the HwndHost.WndProc is only called when the window is visible on screen, or only after the window has been shown on screen at least once?  It's likely that the window handle is not created until the first time the window is shown.  If the window (or its parent) is hidden or minimized after it is shown you should still get messages in the wndproc.

Comment: Until the window is shown on the screen the first time.  Is it possible to draw this window to memory before it is shown?

Or perhaps a workaround would be to spawn in a new window,
Show();
Hide();
Then try to draw?

Comment: Please leave tags like "C#" in the tags, and keep them out of your titles. It's redundant.

Comment: Yes, you can force the window handle to be created before it is actually shown. Accessing the window handle property should be enough to force handle creation (it's an on demand pattern).  Try reading from HwndHost.Handle before starting your screenshot run.

Comment: Simulate a WM_PAINT message by setting up the message arguments You'll need to create a memory DC with the bitmap in it and include in the WM_PAINT args.  SendMessage(HwndHost.Handle, WM_PAINT, etc etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can coerce a window to draw into a bitmap by simulating a WM_PAINT message.  You will need to set up a memory DC and select your destination bitmap into it, then pass that DC handle as an arg in the paint message. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213%28VS.85%29.aspx) for specifics.

Once the args are all ready to roll, do a SendMessage(HwndHost.Handle, WM_PAINT, etc etc). When that call returns, the bitmap should contain the image of the window.

Note that there are many messages involved to fully painting an entire window.  The general pattern is:

1. Invalidate the entire client area of the window.  Otherwise, nothing will be drawn because the clip rect will be empty.
2. Set up your memory bitmap in a memory DC
3. Send a WM_ERASEBKGND message to the window handle, passing in the memory dc handle
4. Send the WM_PAINT message to the window handle, passing in the memory dc handle

The image of the window should now be in the memory bitmap.

If you also want to capture the border, window frame, and window caption of the target window, you will need to simulate the non-client paint message:  WM_NCPAINT is the main one, off the top of my head.

There is also a WM_PRINT message which supposedly helps with drawing into a memory DC destined for printing, but I've had trouble with it several versions of Windows ago.  Child controls not drawing themselves, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this is the direction I began going in last night.  Reading this now, it is even more clear.  Very detailed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[You should not directly send a WM_PAINT message, as per MSDN spec.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213%28VS.85%29.aspx)
You may use [PrintWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since Windows XP, perhaps forcing updates with [RedrawWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) called with the RDW_INTERNALPAINT flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the graphic technique of "double buffering." Once you understand this technique - it's not hard - you will have a solution to your problem. In my  opinion. :-)

Links:

[Win32 Double Buffering](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=411559)

[MSDN Double Buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/double-buffered-graphics) Lots 'O Links

[WinForms Double Buffering](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx) Found through Google - Unknown Quality

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this works in C# with WPF, so I'll just give you the Windows API perspective and hope some of it leads you to a solution.

All drawing is done to a Device Context (DC). When Windows asks you to paint a window, it also gives you access to a DC corresponding to the drawable surface of the window.

To draw without a window, you need to create your own DC and, since the bits aren't going to a window, you need to select a bitmap into the DC to hold the results. In the Windows API you would use `CreateCompatibleDC` and `SelectObject`. Once you have a DC, you paint into it as normal, then deselect the bitmap.